# Result empty in CSV through Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am encountering empty SFMA.csv output while using Pandas DataFrame, meanwhile the code works if I print content . The codes are below:

```
import csv
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
from random import randint 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fi = open('Input_List.csv', 'r')
#readers = list(csv.reader(fi))
readers=csv.reader(fi)
#print(readers)
df = []

for reader in readers:
    #print(str(reader)[1:-1]+"\n")
    url=str(reader)[2:-2]
    request = requests.session()
    htmlpage = requests.get(url)
    #print("status code: "+ str(htmlpage.status_code))
    if htmlpage.status_code != 200 : 
        break    # something went wrong #  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.text,'lxml')
    for result_table in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "w3-container"}):
        #content=result_table.find('p')
        #print(result_table)
        content=result_table.text

        if(content.find("Website") > -1):
            index=content.find("Website")
            content=content[:content.find("\n",index)]
            #print(content)
            df=np.append(df,content)
            break
        #print(content)
        df=np.append(df,str(content))
        #print(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df1.to_csv("SFMA.csv",index=False,encoding='utf-8')

fi.close()
```

output when print(df1) [image: output when print(df1)]
I would be grateful if someone can point out if there is any typo or error. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post sample output of df after the exiting the for loop , just before you assign df1?

Comment: @Satyadev output attached

Comment: Problem spotted, csv fonts in white, hence cannot see... weired

Answer (score 0):

May be read your file in this manner:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/tk/Input_List.csv',  header=0,encoding = 'unicode_escape')
```